# unsupported instruction `lidt`

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I am building a kernel for educational purposes.

Right my OS boots as follows: `GRUB -> boot.S -> init.c`

In `boot.S` I want to load an interrupt descriptor table. This is an excerpt of my file:

```
# load_idt - Loads the interrupt descriptor table (IDT).
# stack: [esp + 4] the address of the first entry in the IDT
#        [esp    ] the return address
load_idt: 
    movl    4(%esp),%eax    # load the address of the IDT into register eax
    lidt   %eax            # load the IDT
    ret                     # return to the calling function
```

I am using gas to compile, so I am working in the at&t syntax.
However when I try and compile this, the compiler doesn't seem to recognize the `lidt` instruction.

> gcc  -Wa,--32 -MMD  -c -o boot.o boot.S boot.S: Assembler messages:
>   boot.S:65: Error: unsupported instruction `lidt' : recipe for
>   target 'boot.o' failed make: *** [boot.o] Error 1

What is the correct instruction then?

**Edit:** I tried using `lidtl`, this doesn't work also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lidt` requires a memory reference. The correct syntax is `lidt (%eax)`. Admittedly, the error message could be better. Then again, my `gas` version (from `GNU Binutils for Debian 2.22`) does say `operand type mismatch for 'lidt'`.

PS: `gas` can be switched to intel syntax, so that's no reason to use at&t. The intel syntax equivalent is of course `lidt [eax]`, and `lidt eax` would produce the same error.

Comment: Great, it works! Its weird since my gas version is 2.24 but I get the unsupported instruction error. Oh well, at least it works now. Thanks